# XML Deserialize Missing Element

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, serialization

I'm deserialising some XML into my class, which is all working fine. What I want to happen is if the XML does not contain an element for one of my class properties, rather than set the property to null, I want to it to be the equivalent of String.Empty.

For example, this is the XML:

```
<Person>
    <Title>Mr</Title>
    <FullName>John Smith</FullName>
</Person>
```

This is the Class:

```
[XmlRoot("Person")]
public sealed class PersonObject
{
    [XmlElement("Title")]
    public string NamePrefix { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("FullName")]
    public string FullName { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("JobTitle")]
    public string JobTitle { get; set; }
}
```

Currently if I deserialise into this object, JobTitle is set to null.  I want this to be set to an empty string, much like it would be if I passed JobTitle in the XML, but had the value set to nothing.

Is it possible to do this using some kind of property on the Serialisation method?

Comment: As far as I can tell you'll probably have to create a custom attribute that inherits from `XmlElementAttribute` in order to accomplish that. I have to ask though, why does `null` matter? Can't you just handle it in your code?

Comment: In the web service method that I call as a result of this, it doesn't handle nulls, and i'd rather not have to do some kind of messy replace.  I know which fields could potentially be null, because I'm sharing the schema across different XML inputs.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You *could* do it with a backing field with a default value:

```
private string jobTitle = "";

[XmlElement("JobTitle")]
public string JobTitle { get {return jobTitle;} set {jobTitle = value;} }
```

or set it in the default constructor:

```
public PersonObject()
{
    JobTitle = "";
    NamePrefix = "";
    FullName = "";
}
```